# Asahi Dry Black beer can

Tags: translation, meaning, expressions

What does ビアホール仕立ての黒 on Asahi Dry Black means?
Specifically 仕立て(sewing?) and ビアホール(via hole?). I tried searching it on japanese web, but it's kinda assumed as common knowledge and never mentioned besides sites about beers.

[image: hi]

Comment: `ビアホール(via hole)` <-- beer hall じゃないの...? 

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> 「[Noun] + 仕立{じた}て」

means:

> "made in the [Noun] style"

「ビアホール」 is an establishment where people gather for the main purpose of drinking draft beer in huge beer mugs.

When I first saw your question, I was going to say that 「ビアホール」 was a 和製英語{わせいえいご} (= "an English word created by the Japanese"), but I have found this place in the U.S., so I am not so sure:

https://www.kochanskisconcertina.com/

In any case, 「ホール」 comes from "hall" and certainly not "hole".  Another word you will eventually need to know is 「ビアガーデン」.

> 「黒{くろ}」

in this context, means:

> "dark beer"

So, the whole phrase means:

> "Dark Beer Brewed in the Beer Hall Style"

Comment: thing that threw me off was that "beer" in japanese would be ビール and not ビア. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, when I sounded out ビアホール, it made me think of the German Bierhalle (and Biergarten - beer gardens), which makes sense as a possible origin of the phrase/word in Japanese.

Comment: When we say "beer" by itself as a drink name, we say ビール, but we say ビアホール、ビアガーデン, etc.  Strange as it may seem, you would sound fairly weird if you said or wrote ビールホール or ビールガーデン.